# How to add a button to ios TableView row

Tags: ios, tableview

I have a text array backing a `TableView` in iOS. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: method I return a UITableViewCell* which is populated with text from the backing array. indexPath is used as the index into the backing array.

I now want to add a "Done" button to the last cell in the `TableView`. In my StoryBoard I've created a second (prototype) `TableView Cell` and gave it the identifier "ButtonCell". I've also added an extra element to the end of the backing array so numberOfRowsInSection: can return the count of the backing array and everything will just work.

I thought I would set the text of the last array element to something like @"donebutton" and then I could check for that in cellForRowAtIndexPath:. If it comes up true, I would know I'm at the end of my array and to return the "ButtonCell" cell instead of the normal "Cell".  Thing is, it's not quite working right. What's the best way to accomplish this?  Code snip is below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   static NSString *ButtonCellIdentifier = @"ButtonCell";
   UITableViewCell *bcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ButtonCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   NSString *rowtext = [_mArCellData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   // return button cell if last item in list
   if ([rowtext isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", SUBMIT_BUTTON]])
   {
      NSLog(@"hit last row, so using button row");
      return bcell;
   }

   cell.textLabel.text = rowtext;
   return cell;
}
```

[image: This is what I'm getting]

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Is your SUBMIT_BUTTON constant an NSInteger? Because you've put %d in your format string. When I've done something like this in the past, I've just checked for indexPath.row == _maArCellData.count

Comment: sha - I think calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is wrong somehow. If I remove the 'if' block all I get is one tablerow filled with 'Done' buttons. I've updated with screenshot.  ksimons - Yes, many ways to do this. Yours is favorable over my test code.

Comment: put the `NSLog (@"rowText: %@; SUBMIT_BUTTON: %d", rowText,SUBMIT_BUTTON);` before the `if (...)` condition and you should soon pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString *ButtonCellIdentifier = @"ButtonCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (indexPath.row != ([_mArCellData count] - 1) { // if not the last row

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        // configure cell...

    } else { // last row

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ButtonCell];
        // configure button cell...
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this was it. Calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier twice seems to be causing my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would just change your if statement to:

```
if ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] == indexPath.row + 1) {
   NSLog(@"hit last row, so using button row");
   bcell.textLabel.text = rowtext;
   return bcell;
}
```

This is a little more abstracted than your solution and doesn't rely on a property of a cell being set to anything in particular. I like the way @bilobatum put the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: call in the if statement. That should save some memory as well.

EDIT: I also noticed that you are setting cell text, but not bcell text.